# DAE solver fails for system of coupled partial differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I am trying to run the following code to solve a system of coupled differential equation:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ρ0 = 1;
M = 1;
eq1 = D[ρ[r, t], t] R[r, t] D[R[r, t], r] + 
   1/3 D[ρ[r, t], r] R[r, t] D[R[r, t], t] + 
   10/3  ρ[r, t] D[R[r, t], r] + 
   4/3 ρ[r, t] R[r, t] D[R[r, t], r, t];
eq2 = Simplify[
   D[R[r, t], r, t] + 
    D[R[r, t], 
      r] (3/2 D[ρ[r, t], t]/ρ[r, t] - 
       4 D[R[r, t], t]/R[r, t]) + 
    D[R[r, t], t] D[ρ[r, t], r]/(4 ρ[r, t])];
{Ro, Ra} = 
 NDSolveValue[{eq1 == 0, 
   eq2 == 0, ρ[r, 0] == ρ0, ρ[0, t] == ρ0, 
   R[r, 0] == ((3 M)/(4 Pi ρ0))^(1/3), 
   R[0, t] == ((3 M)/(4 Pi ρ0))^(1/3)}, {ρ, R}, {r, 0, 
   1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

but I get the error:

> NDSolveValue::indexss: The DAE solver failed at r = 0.`. The solver is intended for index 1 DAE systems and structural analysis indicates that the DAE is structurally singular

I tried to read [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html) page on DAE, but I did not understand most of it. How can I solve my system?

Comment: It's running on my machine (V12.2, Macbook Pro), but it's taking a long time.  What is the message name of the error message?

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes it takes a while also on my machine running version 11.3. The error message is `NDSolveValue::indexss`

Comment: I eventually got the message. I thought it had succeeded because it was running. I usually warn people of things that take more than a few seconds. (If I hadn't had something else to work on, I might have just killed it and moved on. The first time I ran it, the kernel died fairly quickly.)

Comment: Try `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t}` and see what you think.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It worked thanks. What does that option do exactly? Could you point a page in the documentation?

Comment: Here's the tutorial: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html -- My guess is that `NDSolve` chose `x` for the temporal variable instead of `t`, and the resulting system was a pain. It's not a guaranteed cure, just something different to try.

Comment: If you can maintain the discipline of keeping the temporal variable first in the function and domain specification, Mathematica will generally have better luck parsing.  I switched the order to [t,r] and it solved without the additional `Method` specification.  @Michael E2's approach is more explicit if you do not want to rely on the black box.